# How to virtual List control using a map data structure'?

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I have a question while studying C++ MFC.

```
void AnchorDlg::OnGetdispinfoListctrl(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{

    NMLVDISPINFO *pDispInfo = reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFO*>(pNMHDR);

    LV_ITEM* pItem = &(pDispInfo)->item;
    CString str;
    if(pItem == NULL) return;

    int nRow = pItem->iItem;
    int nCol = pItem->iSubItem;

    if(nRow<0 || nRow >= mapShip->size()) return;

    auto iter = mapShip->begin();

    if(pItem->pszText)
    {
        switch(nCol)
        {
        case 1:
            str.Format(_T("%.0f"), iter->second->mmsi);
            //str.Format(_T("%.0f"), iter->second->mmsi);
            lstrcpy(pItem->pszText, str);
            break;
        case 2:
            str.Format(_T("%.7f"), iter->second->lat);
            lstrcpy(pItem->pszText, str);
            break;
        case 3:
            str.Format(_T("%.7f"), iter->second->lng);
            lstrcpy(pItem->pszText, str);
            break;
        case 4:
            str.Format(_T("%.1f"), iter->second->sog);
            lstrcpy(pItem->pszText, str);
        case 5:
            str.Format(_T("%.1f"), iter->second->cog);
            lstrcpy(pItem->pszText, str);
        }
    }
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

`mapShip` consists of double and data objects.

I want to print out 1000 data, but only one data is printed.

I've used iter but only one data is output. Same data print repeat.

I must used map data structure.

I don't know how to use the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to do anything with `pItem->iItem` (`nRow`), you just set it to the beginning of the list. You should instead search your data with this - requests may arrive in any random order. You don't have to iterate the list in `OnGetdispinfoListctrl()`, instead you should return the data to be displayed, given the `iItem` and `iSubItem` members. So consider using a more efficient structure to hold your data, if they are really too many (lists are not, because they are serial access structures, not random access ones). Also, don't copy the text into `Item.pszText`, instead set `Item.pszText` to point to your data. The `if(pItem->pszText)` check is not needed, neither is correct:

```
void AnchorDlg::OnGetdispinfoListctrl(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    NMLVDISPINFO *pDispInfo = reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFO*>(pNMHDR);

    LV_ITEM* pItem = &(pDispInfo)->item;

    // Persistent Buffer
    static CString str;

    if (pItem == NULL) return;

    int nRow = pItem->iItem;
    int nCol = pItem->iSubItem;

    if (nRow < 0 || nRow >= mapShip->size()) return;

    if (Item.mask & LVIF_TEXT) //Item/subItem text
    {
        //auto iter = mapShip->begin();
        auto pValue = SearchMyData(nRow);

        switch (nCol)
        {
            case 1:
                str.Format(_T("%.0f"), pValue->mmsi);
                break;
            case 2:
                str.Format(_T("%.7f"), pValue->lat);
                break;
            case 3:
                str.Format(_T("%.7f"), pValue->lng);
                break;
            case 4:
                str.Format(_T("%.1f"), pValue->sog);
                break;
            case 5:
                str.Format(_T("%.1f"), pValue->cog);
                break;
        }
        pItem->pszText = const_cast<LPTSTR>((LPCTSTR)str);
    }
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here is a excerpt from the documentation about the [**LV_ITEM**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-lvitema) structure:

`pszText`
*If the structure specifies item attributes, pszText is a pointer to a null-terminated string containing the item text. When responding to an LVN_GETDISPINFO notification, be sure that this pointer remains valid until after the next notification has been received.*

Also:
`cchTextMax`
*This member is only used when the structure receives item attributes. ... It is read-only during LVN_GETDISPINFO and other LVN_ notifications.*

And the example in the [**LVN_GETDISPINFO**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvn-getdispinfo) documentation does exactly this, ie sets the `pszText` pointer rather than copies text into it.

Also, you shouldn't get the conversion error if you are using either the multibyte (ANSI) or the wide (Unicode) version of both the `LVITEM` and `CString`, which you seem to do (you do not set them explicitly, which is OK, it defaults to `T` interpretation). It must be a `const` conflict. So, either use a `const_cast`:

```
    pItem->pszText = const_cast<LPTSTR>((LPCTSTR)str);
```

or a char array instead:

```
    static TCHAR _szItem[MAX_LEN]; // Persistent buffer
    .
    .
    CString str;
    str.Format(_T("%.0f"), iter->second->mmsi));
    _tcscpy_s(_szItem, str);
    pItem->pszText = _szItem;
    break;
```

Comment: hello thank you for your answer,, i have a question.  
You tell me to create a function called SearchMyData? I can't understand because I can't speak English well
Also i change to 'pItem->pszText', I could not convert form 'error c2440 '=' : 'CString' to 'LPSTR'.

Comment: *"don't copy the text into `Item.pszText`, instead set `Item.pszText` to point to your data."* - That's wrong. You *do* want to copy text into the system-provided buffer `pszText` (see [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-virtual-list-view-controls)). You *can* set `pszText` to point at your data, but if you do, you'll need to make sure the data persists. This proposed answer has *all* items point at the same `static` instance. If you're lucky, anyway. When you run out of luck and `Format` needs to re-allocate, previous `pszText`s point into deallocated memory.

Comment: I sovled this problem your answer was helpful. thank you! Constantine

Comment: @Hunni, Edited the asnwer, providing some more information. Also modified the code a litle, added the `if (Item.mask & LVIF_TEXT)` check. As for your comment, yes, given the row and col numbers you must search your data and return the information requested (items' and subitems' text).

Comment: @IInspectable, it's not wrong, this is what the sample in the `LVN_DISPINFO` does (pls check my EDIT above). It can work both ways as it seems. The sample you linked may not be the best, it doesn't even use the `cchTextMax` member, it uses `MAX_COUNT` instead. As for the text buffer, it only needs to remain in place just immediately after the notification-handling routine returns (_until after the next notification has been received_, per the documentation), the system uses it to display the requested text, and does NOT store it, it's a virtual list-view control after all.

Comment: @Constantine thank you your answer i solved this problem

Answer (score 1):

A [virtual list-view control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview#creating-a-virtual-list-view-control) is a list-view control that doesn't store any data. Instead, users just tell the control how many items there are (by sending a [`LVM_SETITEMCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-setitemcount) message), and the control implementation will subsequently call back to the user to provide the data for the individual cells (by way of the [`LVN_GETDISPINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvn-getdispinfo) message).

While the code in question is responding to the `LVN_GETDISPINFO` message, evaluating the `nRow` (and `nCol`) identifying the cell to be displayed, it doesn't use that data for information lookup. The code perpetually accesses the first item (`mapShip->begin()`) for display. However, it should be using `nRow` to index into the data represented by `mapShip` (see [How to Use Virtual List-View Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-virtual-list-view-controls) for an example).

Assuming that `mapShip` is an instantiation of the [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) class template, you'll want to index into that map using `nRow` as the index, e.g.:

```cpp
auto const& value = mapShip[nRow];
```

and use `value` in place of `iter`. This will display items in the order they are stored in the associative container (sorted by key). If you need a different ordering, you'll have to map `nRow` onto the respective index in the map.